# What are the CURRENT advantages of the VMware Workstation over the VMware Player?

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VMWare Player vs Workstation](https://superuser.com/questions/62041/vmware-player-vs-workstation)

There's a [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/62041/vmware-player-vs-workstation) asking about the same, however, it's answer is outdated and incomplete. I was looking for an answer [on the VMWare page](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/overview.html), but it contains mostly marketing speech like "Gain an Indispensable Tool". Neither the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware#Products) nor Google helped me. Incidentally, I've found out that (unlike the Player) the Workstation is capable of [shrinking](https://superuser.com/questions/323728/how-can-i-shrink-my-vmware-image) the image and making snapshots. What other advantages does it offer?

<sup>As I said my question is a sort of duplicate and probably should be merged into the older one. However, this is not something I can do, so I think my question should get a chance to be answered and should be merged later with the old one. Otherwise the information will be missing on this site.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[VMFAQ.com has a decent overview](http://vmfaq.com/entry/5/)

I have included the comparison table below but follow the link above fore more detailed info.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think VMware has or had an idea that "VMWare Images" could become a sort of common
currency for distributing virtual systems, so VMware Workstation is the builder application
you have to pay for, whereas VMware player is the free "user" program.  Think of Adobe Acrobat which costs $$$ and Acrobat Reader which is free.

Not what you asked, but you should look at alternatives such as virtualbox which
is completely free.